# Is resolve function passed to Promise executor async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following code:

```
function myPromiseFunc() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(Promise.resolve(123));
  });
}
```

As we know `Promise.resolve` method resolves Promise with a plain value immediately.
So `Promise.resolve(123) -> Promise<fulfilled>`
But:

```
console.log(myPromiseFunc());
```

will return Promise with status `pending`. Why? **Is resolve function passed to executor async?** Cause this:

```
setTimeout(console.log, 0, res);
```

will return `Promise<fulfilled>`.

I know Promises use microtasks but it's supposed to use only for handlers.

[Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) says:

[[Resolve]](promise, x) -> `If/when x is a promise and fulfilled, fulfill promise with the same value.`

By the way. This snipped will return `Promise<fulfilled>`:

```
function myPromiseFunc() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(123);
  });
}
```

So it looks like `resolve` is async only when Promise passed as a value.

Please, help to understand. Thank you!

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know. That's just a theoretical question.  Why do I have `pending` status instead of `fulfilled`?

Comment: Use `myPromiseFunc().then(console.log)` to see the resolved output.

Comment: I do not want to see the resolved output :) I want to understand do Promises change their statuses async or what is going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-resolve-functions) of the `resolve` function passed to the executor in `new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...)`:

When a promise resolve function is called with argument `resolution`, the following steps are taken:

1. Let `F` be the active function object.
2. Assert: `F` has a `[[Promise]]` internal slot whose value is an Object.
3. Let `promise` be `F.[[Promise]]`.
4. Let `alreadyResolved` be `F.[[AlreadyResolved]]`.
5. If `alreadyResolved.[[Value]]` is `true`, return `undefined`.
6. Set `alreadyResolved.[[Value]]` to `true`.
7. If `SameValue(resolution, promise)` is `true`, then

   1. Let `selfResolutionError` be a newly created `TypeError` object.
   2. Return `RejectPromise(promise, selfResolutionError)`.
8. If `Type(resolution)` is not Object, then

   1. Return `FulfillPromise(promise, resolution)`.
9. Let `then` be `Get(resolution, "then")`.
10. If `then` is an abrupt completion, then

    1. Return `RejectPromise(promise, then.[[Value]])`.
11. Let `thenAction` be `then.[[Value]]`.
12. If `IsCallable(thenAction)` is `false`, then

    1. Return `FulfillPromise(promise, resolution)`.
13. Let `thenJobCallback` be `HostMakeJobCallback(thenAction)`.
14. Let `job` be `NewPromiseResolveThenableJob(promise, resolution, thenJobCallback)`.
15. Perform `HostEnqueuePromiseJob(job.[[Job]], job.[[Realm]])`.
16. Return `undefined`.

Lots of technical jargon, but the most important bits for your question is that  `resolution`  is the value you passed to it. If it's (roughly) a non-Promise, you'll end up either in `8.1` (for non-objects) or `12.1` (for a missing or non-callable `then` field), which will all immediately fulfill the promise. If you passed a value with a `then` function (e.g. a Promise), it'll do all the steps starting from `13` where it basically queues up the `.then` and follows the whole "my fulfillment depends on another Promise's fulfillment".

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you! I looked through the specification but didn't get it.

Comment: Good explanation. Correct me if I am wrong. It means `resolve` is not passed to function in async but depends on the argument that you pass to the `resolve` to determine what will happen next.

Comment: Calling `resolve` will **immediately** fulfill the Promise (unless you call it with another Promise, in which case it queues calling `.then`, i.e. step 13+). The executor, as in the function you pass to `new Promise(...)` is immediately (synchronously) called. But yes, based on the value passed to `resolve`, it'll either be "fulfill immediately" or "queue `.then`".