# What happens exactly when I call Promise.resolve() on a promise (from the perspective of event loop)?

Tags: javascript, promise

Here's the simplified code structure:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(new Promise(resolve => resolve(1)))
}).then(() => {
    console.log('tick 3')
}).then(() => {
    console.log('tick 4')
})

new Promise(resolve => resolve(1)).then(() => {
    console.log('tick 1')
}).then(() => {
    console.log('tick 2')
})
```

The console logs:

```
tick 1
tick 2
tick 3
tick 4
```

My question is, why does the callback function that logs `tick 3` execute 2 "tick"s (or event loops, not sure how to describe it properly) later than the callback that logs `tick 1` rather than only 1 "tick"s? If the `tick 3` function executes only 1 "tick" later than the `tick 1` function, `tick 3` should be logged earlier than `tick 2` since it enters the task queue earlier.

I tried looking up docs on MDN like this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve, but only found this sentence related to my question, which is obviously no help here:

> The `Promise.resolve()` method returns a Promise object that is resolved with a given value. If the value is a promise, that promise is returned.

So what exactly happens inside Promise.resolve() when it receives a promise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not using `Promise.resolve()` anywhere. You're using the [`resolutionFunc` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters) passed to the executor callback.

Comment: There are multiple ticks involved when resolving a promise with another promise. That's about it. The exact number of ticks is not necessarily the same every time. You should ***NEVER*** rely on this kind of information for your code.

Comment: Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704448/14032355), the answer will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this:

```
Promise.resolve = (value) => {
   if (value instanceof Promise) return value;
   
   return new Promise(resolve => resolve(value));
}
```

If you pass it a promise, it just returns the promise back. If you pass it a non-promise, it wraps it in a promise that resolves with that value.